# How to create dell store 2 test database on OS X?

Tags: postgresql

I have heard about the 'dell store 2' test database and I'd like to import it on my system. 3 sizes are mentioned: 10MB, 1GB and 100Gb, and I'd like to import medium size - 1GB.

The 'dell store 2' project is available on [this link](http://linux.dell.com/dvdstore/).
I've followed the instructions in the readme, but I couldn't do much. The docs are awfully bad: there's a readme file in **every** project subfolder and there's a lot of doc repetition. The creators persistently try to explain project structure and how things work, leaving out the important stuff like: does it work on Linux and OS X (there are `*.exe` files everywhere) and the basic terms like what is a `driver` (also mentioned everywhere but defined nowhere).

I'm running postgresql 9.4beta2 on OS X 10.9.4.

My questions are:

- is it even possible to import 1GB postgresql database on OS X?
- where to find simple steps how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you download ds21.tar.gz and ds21_postgresql.tar.gz

Then, edit the shell-scripts to fix connection settings etc and run the create scripts through `pgsqlds2_create_all.sh`.

Then, run the relevant creation scripts in `cust`, `orders` and `prod` to create CSV files to import. Then, import the tables.

Which bit is causing you problems?

Comment: I can run the `pgsqlds2_create_all.sh` script and it creates the default 'small' 10Mb database - that's good. Now, how do I create the 1GB database? I tried running `Install_DVDStore.pl` script but it outputs errors while trying to edit some `*.exe` files. Running the `pgsqlds2_create_all.sh` after that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Look at the data_files scripts in cust, orders and prod - they can generate small/med/large sets of data (or you can supply your own values).